# WPF Canvas not placing objects as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I just began learning WPF and XAML, and I was taking a look at the things I could do in Blend.

So what I tried was placing a rectangle in a grid.

Grid size: 517x319 (auto)

Rectangle size: 497x299 (auto)

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="UITest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UITest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And it gave this output

[image]

But when I tried doing the same thing with a canvas,

Canvas size: 517x319 (auto)

Rectangle size: 497x299 (auto)

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="UITest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UITest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="299" Width="497" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

it renders into

[image]

And then I tried the same thing again... this time: Grid -> Canvas -> Rectangle, and this is what I got

Grid size: 517x319 (auto)

Canvas size: 497x299 (auto)

Rectangle size: 477x279 (auto)

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="UITest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UITest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Margin="10" Background="Black">
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="279" Width="477" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Stroke="Black"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Why isn't the rectangle being placed in the center of the canvas?

Comment: I am not a Blend user, but I recommend checking all the margins and paddings.

Comment: @Jai All paddings, borders, and margins are zero... except those mentioned in the XAML code

Comment: Ok, so, apparently centering something in a canvas isn't as easy as just setting values, so you should take a look at this article: http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/centeringelementsonacanvasinwp/

Comment: @Spluf that article is really great... you should write a brief answer below if you want to... I'm pretty sure this is going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad I could help :).

It looks like centering content in WPF canvas is a bit tricky because of Windows (when adding the title bar and practically the entire frame for running the app it messes the sizes a bit). A solution to this is using a converter to get the height and width from the running app and calculate the center points.

So this is how that might look like:

```
public class HalfValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{

    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values,
                          Type targetType,
                          object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length < 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "HalfValueConverter expects 2 double values to be passed" +
                " in this order -> totalWidth, width",
                "values");
        }

        double totalWidth = (double)values[0];
        double width = (double)values[1];
        return (object)((totalWidth - width) / 2);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value,
                                Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter,
                                CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and here is the XML for your case:

```
<Window x:Class="UITest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UITest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:HalfValueConverter x:Key="HalfValue" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas">
            <Rectangle Fill="Black"
                   Height="299"
                   Width="497"
                   x:Name="rectangle"
                   >
                <Canvas.Left>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HalfValue}">
                        <Binding ElementName="canvas" Path="ActualWidth" />
                        <Binding ElementName="rectangle" Path="ActualWidth" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Canvas.Left>
                <Canvas.Top>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HalfValue}">
                        <Binding ElementName="canvas" Path="ActualHeight" />
                        <Binding ElementName="rectangle" Path="ActualHeight" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Canvas.Top>
            </Rectangle>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is a good article on how to do this:
http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/centeringelementsonacanvasinwp/

Comment: set the width and height with the `*` or remove them completely so it will take the remaining space. You have a fixed value so there isn't enough space to set all the margins I guess.

Comment: Ok, so, apparently centering something in a canvas isn't as easy as just setting values, so you should take a look at this article: http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/centeringelementsonacanvasinwp/

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you took the `Grid` and `Canvas` sizes from properties pane. If that's the case, the problem is that these are sizes computed at design-time, and are different (at least at my side) than the sizes computed at run-time (the outer element was actually 509x311 at run-time and not 517x319).

I believe that's caused by some window resizing policy - I remember reading that windows have extra invisible borders around them so that you don't have to precisely hit it's visible border in order to resize it (the cursor only needs to be *"close enough"*) . Unfortunately, I can't seem to find this link, but I'll post it as soon as I find it.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the sizes that were auto-generated in the properties pane. It has to be the window resizing thing.

Comment: The link given by Spluf in the comments is a good one... if you have a different link, please share it